# PostgreSQL Stored procedure performance

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL and I have a table 'PERSON' in schema 'public' that looks like this:

```
    +----+-------------+-------+----------------------------+
    | id | internal_id | name  | created                    |
    +----+-------------+-------+----------------------------+
    | 1  | P0001-XX00  |  Bob  |  2021-05-24 22:10:01.93025 |
    +----+-------------+-------+----------------------------+
    | 2  | P0001-CX00  |  Tom  |  2021-06-27 22:10:01.93025 |
    +----+-------------+-------+----------------------------+
    | 3  | P0002-XX00  |  Anna |  2021-05-24 22:10:01.93025 |    
    +----+-------------+-------+----------------------------+

id -> bigint; internal_id -> character varying; name -> character varying; created  -> timestamp without timezone
```

I need to write procedure that delete those records that are older than fixed timestamp, for example: now(). But as soon as such an old record has been found, I need to check if there are other records in the table which are not old yet and with the same first 5 characters in `internal_id` as the found old record. If there are such records, then I should not delete the old record.

So I wrote the following procedure with plpgsql and it seems to work:

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM public."PERSON" AS t1
   WHERE t1.created < now()
   AND NOT EXISTS
     (
      SELECT 
      FROM   public."PERSON" AS t2 
      WHERE  left(t2.internal_id, 5) = left(t1.internal_id, 5) 
      AND    t2.created >= now()
     );
COMMIT;
END;
```

Questions:

1. Could it have been made more correct or prettier or cleaner? Perhaps, instead of using the `left()` function, it was necessary to use `LIKE`, or, in principle, to do it somehow differently?
2. Do you think this procedure has normal performance or it can be improved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "*Could it have been made more correct?*" - only you can tell whether it works or not. "*Do you think this procedure has normal performance?*" - yes. Is it fast enough for you? Then you're done. Otherwise, please post the query execution plan and what indices you have on your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work just fine.

For good performance, create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public."PERSON" (left(internal_id, 5), created);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, will make an index!